# Apache 413 Request Entity Too Large with large string

Tags: apache

Recently i change to a dedicated server and i start having problems to save large string in a jquery ajax post. in the old server works fine's but in this new server i get an Apache 413 error.

Firebug send this response:

```
Encabezados de la respuesta
Connection  close
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Length  331
Content-Type    text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Date    Mon, 06 Aug 2012 20:53:23 GMT
Server  Apache
Vary    Accept-Encoding
Encabezados de la petición
Accept  */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language es-MX,es;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Length  1105294
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie  SpryMedia_DataTables_table-objetos_crear.php=%7B%22iCreate%22%3A1344285216690%2C%22iStart%22%3A0%2C%22iEnd%22%3A10%2C%22iLength%22%3A10%2C%22sFilter%22%3A%22%22%2C%22sFilterEsc%22%3Atrue%2C%22aaSorting%22%3A%5B%20%5B1%2C%22asc%22%5D%5D%2C%22aaSearchCols%22%3A%5B%20%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%5D%2C%22abVisCols%22%3A%5B%20true%2Ctrue%2Ctrue%2Ctrue%2Ctrue%5D%7D; SpryMedia_DataTables_confs-tabla_index.php=%7B%22iCreate%22%3A1344286395266%2C%22iStart%22%3A0%2C%22iEnd%22%3A8%2C%22iLength%22%3A10%2C%22sFilter%22%3A%22%22%2C%22sFilterEsc%22%3Atrue%2C%22aaSorting%22%3A%5B%20%5B8%2C%22desc%22%5D%2C%5B4%2C%22asc%22%5D%2C%5B0%2C%22asc%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22asc%22%5D%2C%5B2%2C%22asc%22%5D%5D%2C%22aaSearchCols%22%3A%5B%20%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%5D%2C%22abVisCols%22%3A%5B%20true%2Ctrue%2Ctrue%2Ctrue%2Ctrue%2Ctrue%2Ctrue%2Ctrue%2Cfalse%2Ctrue%2Cfalse%5D%7D; PHPSESSID=3d8f502be166becd4e504a438eb2b4ae; chkFiltroCol2=; COL=misconfs; ACCION=CONF_EDITAR_CONTENIDO; CONF_ID=279
Host    eduweb.mx
Referer http://myserver.com/edit-article.php
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

Googling i found the error was in the size of LimitRequestBody, i change it to 64Mb but i still getting this error.

any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

It's what worked for me:

in modsecurity.conf file

On my Ubuntu 14.04 the config file is here but this really depends on the system:/etc/modsecurity/modsecurity.conf

change this two commands to this values:

SecRequestBodyLimit 13107200

SecRequestBodyNoFilesLimit 13107200

Answer (score 1):

`LimitRequestBody` is probably not what you want. That's the request *body*, not the headers which is what it looks like is too long. Try setting [the LimitRequestFieldSize](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestfieldsize), which by default is 8k, to something larger (Note the warning about precedence about this setting).

Comment: I added LimitRequestFieldSize to my httpd.conf (LimitRequestFieldSize 2097152) but still not working

Answer (score 1):

You may be bumping into an SSL renegotiate buffer overflow situation.  Check your Apache log file.  The quick fix if this is the case is to use the SSLRenegBufferSize directive to increase your renegotiate buffer.  See [SSL Renegotiation with Client Certificate causes Server Buffer Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14281628/ssl-renegotiation-with-client-certificate-causes-server-buffer-overflow)