# Facing error: 413 Request Entity Too Large

Tags: php, apache, laravel-5

I am facing error

> 413 Request Entity Too Large

while uploading big image through Ajax - POST method. I tried plenty of solutions from google, but still no luck.

My Website is hosted on GoDaddy shared hosting. I have increased all the memory settings in php.ini too (Through cPanel). but still getting same error.

Website is developed in LARAVEL framework.

Comment: There are a lot of settings that can cause this, if you're on shared hosting you might not have permission to change them all. There's a useful list of settings to check [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9691395/1941241) to a similar question. If those don't work, you can try some Apache settings (if GoDaddy will let you) from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836537/apache-413-request-entity-too-large-with-large-string).

Comment: did you try to contact GoDaddy team?

Comment: Yes ..i tried contacting GoDaddy team.. but they don't have coding expert unfortunately...  they just check uploading image through FTP and confirm that everything is fine from their end.. that't it... :(